# Is it possible to not have an Accordion opened by default in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, accordion

I'm using : http://www.javaswingcomponents.com/product/accordion

It works well but let's say I have this code :

```
    JSCAccordion accordion = new JSCAccordion();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        accordion.addTab("test", new JLabel("I want this closed !"));
```

The result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo5t2.png).

As you can see, the first tab is opened by default.
Is it possible to not have any tab open ?

I know that

```
accordion.setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex);
```

exists, but that just changes the tab that is opened and I was wondering is there is a way to not have any tab opened by default.

Comment: I'm not sure, because I never used this component, but have you tried to set the selection index to -1? `accordion.setSelectedIndex(-1);`

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy No, I already tried and it just give an array index out of bounds exception.
Same thing if i set the index to 21 if there's only 20 tabs.